# How to make input/dropdown using codeigniter form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm using a codeigniter and use form_help for form. I have a dropdown list but I have a lot of data from my dropdown list so I want to make a input a text and autodetect values on dropdown list.

I use this guide https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html
but I cannot find my solution.

check this reference for desire output

[image]

My result and code

```
 <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label"><?php echo $required_notice . $val_option['option'] ?><?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>

                <div class="controls">
                <?php
                if (isset($options_lang[$key][$key_option])) {
                $drop_options = array_combine(explode(',', check_combine_set(isset($options_lang[$key]) ? $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values : '', $val_option['values'], '')), explode(',', check_combine_set($val_option['values'], isset($options_lang[$key]) ? $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->values : '', '')));
                } else {
                $drop_options = array();
                }

                $drop_selected = set_value('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, isset($estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key]) ? $estate['option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key] : '');

                echo form_dropdown('option' . $val_option['id'] . '_' . $key, $drop_options, $drop_selected, 'class="form-control" id="inputOption_' . $key . '_' . $val_option['id'] . '" placeholder="' . $val_option['option'] . '" ' . $required_text)
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Result

[image]

Thankyou !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is worked for me.
You can use `select2.js` for your requirement. See this [website](https://select2.org/configuration).

This is just an example that may help you.
You have just to set `CI select` with this `js`.
The class of `form select` would be same in your `$('.class_of_your_select').select2({`.

In header,

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In your form,

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single">

    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>BCD</option>
    <option>CDE</option>
    <option>DEF</option>
    <option>EFG</option>
    <option>FGh</option>

</select>
```

In your footer,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an option'
});  
</script>
```

Comment: I follow this instruction form Works properly but the problem is no value on my dropdown list

Comment: Got it now Thanks :)

Comment: Great..!!Happy to help..!!